# How to access a CollectionView header when scrolled off screen (ie not visible)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have images in my CollectionView headers and want to access them when a button is clicked.

I have used

```
 let cell = collectionView(collectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: headerIndexPath) as? ListItemHeaderReusableView
```

But this line of code reloads the override func of the header which I don't want because the images are then removed from the header.

Also tried

```
 let ncell = collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath) as? ListItemHeaderReusableView
```

This for some reason returns the cell on the simulator but returns nil on a device.

How can I access the header when it's not visible and content not reloaded.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “access”?

Comment: By access, i mean access images applied to the header when the header is scrolled off-screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can retain your header as a property.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let header = ListItemHeaderReusableView()

     //  here is your custom collectionView header
     //  you have it as a property
     //  so you retain it, it will not be reloaded when you scroll

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        // do some custom config
        return header
    }


    // more methods
}
```